# I am unable to package an appjs app on OS X

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, appjs

I'm unclear, is it possible to install appjs using npm on a mac?

The appjs distributable works fine, but I wanted to package up the app.

The following:

```
node --harmony data/app.js
```

Returns:

```
/Users/richard/Downloads/app/data/node_modules/appjs/lib/bindings.js:9
  throw new Error("AppJS requires Node.js v0.8");
        ^
Error: AppJS requires Node.js v0.8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/richard/Downloads/app/data/node_modules/appjs/lib/bindings.js:9:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/richard/Downloads/app/data/node_modules/appjs/lib/window.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I installed node from source in 32 bit mode:

```
./configure --dest-cpu=ia32
make
sudo make install
```

I assumed the issue above is because the appjs distributable version is out of sync with my local node version. So I tried installing appjs using npm, which returned the following:

```
npm install appjs

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs/-/appjs-0.0.20.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs/-/appjs-0.0.20.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.9.tgz

> appjs@0.0.20 postinstall /Users/richard/dev/product-builder/node_modules/appjs
> node cli/postinstall.js

Installing appjs-darwin package...
Error installing appjs-darwin
Please use `npm install appjs-darwin and install the package manually
appjs@0.0.20 node_modules/appjs
└── mime@1.2.9

npm install appjs-darwin

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs-darwin
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs-darwin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs-darwin/-/appjs-darwin-0.0.19.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/appjs-darwin/-/appjs-darwin-0.0.19.tgz
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Is OS X not supported at the moment or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The first error may very well have been caused by this: https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/328 . It was only fixed two months ago, but since then, there doesn't seem to have been a release.

Answer (score 2):

npm install OS X install is currently marked as broken (https://github.com/appjs/appjs)

[image]

Also there seems to be a bug in App.js version check    https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/328

Please check below note from AppJs as well

"AppJS requires 32bit Node on OS X. It works on 64bit OS X but Node must be 32bit. We're working on solving this, but it's a limitation of Chrome itself so it's a work in progress."

Comment: Node on OSX (at least the latest versions) are fat binaries, containing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions in the same executable. You can pick which version to use using `arch -32 node ...` or `arch -64 node ...`.

Comment: OP states he has installed Node.js from source in 32 bit mode.